# How to disable "Radio device: rtw_8821ce"

Tags: drivers, power-management, battery

I use usb wifi adapter on my laptop with ubuntu 23.10, but "Radio device: rtw_8821ce" keeps turning on and drains my battery, I would like to completely disable it, since I dont need it and would like to reduce energy consumption and improve battery life. I tried to blacklist it in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf, bud it didnt help.
Thank you in advance for help!